# startService() from the service class itself

Tags: android

I try to start an android service from the service's class.
The reason to do this is to achieve some platform independence.

Doing this I get a NullPointerException at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:326). The platform target is 2.1-update1, any suggestions?

See the code below (I left the imports out to save some space)

```
/* GUI: HelloAndroid.java */
package com.example.helloandroid;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // that works!
        startService(new Intent("com.example.helloandroid.UnusualService"));

        // stop the service works of course, too
        stopService(new Intent("com.example.helloandroid.UnusualService"));

        // unusual start does not work:
        UnusualService myService = new UnusualService();
        myService.startService();
    }
}

/* Service: UnusualService.java */
package com.example.helloandroid;

public class UnusualService extends Service {    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.service_started, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.service_stopped, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null; // make something here when the rest works 
    }

    public void startService() {
        // folowing line will cause the NullPointerException
        startService(new Intent("com.example.helloandroid.UnusualService"));
    }

    public void stopService() {
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course - your newly created service does not have a reference to a context, so the context is `null` and therefore the system throws a `NullPointerException`.
Remember: Do not create a service on your own by using `new` - the system does this for you!

Answer (score 4):

Your `UnusualService` extends `Service`. Service extends `ContextWrapper` which contains `Context`.
So when you call `UnusualService.startService(new Intent("..."))` it actually calls `ContextWrapper.startService()` which calls `context.startService()`. However at this point context is null and `NullPointerException` occurs.

```
public abstract class Service extends ContextWrapper implements ComponentCallbacks {
    private static final String TAG = "Service";

    public Service() {
        super(null);
    }

    //...
}


public class ContextWrapper extends Context {
    Context mBase;

    public ContextWrapper(Context base) {
        mBase = base;
    }

    @Override
    public ComponentName startService(Intent service) {
        return mBase.startService(service);
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public void startService() {
    // folowing line will cause the NullPointerException
    startService(new Intent("com.example.helloandroid.UnusualService"));
}
```

do this instead...

```
startService(new Intent(UnusualService.this, UnusualService.class));
```

Edit: Corrected as per CyprUS